# Setting up Wordpress and Flask on Apache2

Tags: python, wordpress, flask, apache2

Im learning flask and got the "hello world" tutorial to work as I was able to access it from the internet.  I then installed wordpress and soon learned that both couldn't be accessible from example.com with my current configuration.  Right now, I'm only able to access wordpress.  I tried changing flask to things like www.example.com/flask/ but was not able to access the test page.

My config files for flask and apache2 are as follows:

app:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "Flask works?"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

conf:

```
#Listen 80
ServerName www.example.com

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #ServerName example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess flask user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 python-path=/var/www/FlaskApp

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
    <Directory "/var/www/FlaskApp/">
        WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = "secretstuff"
```

Then I installed WordPress and realized that they were both on port 80.  As a result, I couldn't reach my Flask test page.

1. Should Flask and Wordpress be on different ports?
2. How would I go about configuring apache2 to allow me to "access flask" via flask.example.com?
3. I've read that I possibly need to adjust my host file.  Is this true?

I realize that this may be an obvious fix to some of you out there.  Nevertheless, I'm a novice and stuck.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Aside from a couple of mistakes in the code I corrected ( wasn't pointed correctly), the main issue was changing

```
app.run()
```

to

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

No clue if this is a secure thing to do or not...

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache [Name-based](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html). In `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

`flaskapp.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  flaskapp.yoursite.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=wilson group=wilson threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/flaskapp.wsgi

    <Directory /path/to/flaskapp/>
        WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

`wordpress.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  blog.yoursite.com

    DocumentRoot /path/to/wordpress

    <Directory /path/to/wordpress/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Reload apache confs:

```
a2ensite flaskapp.conf
a2ensite wordpress.conf
service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Would this approach work if you wanted the blog to be in a subdirectory (e.g. `/blog`) rather than a subdomain?